# Android wear app won't install

Tags: android, eclipse, wear-os

I have developed a android app with a wear app. Now I like to release the app but if I make a release mobile APK with the wear APK included the wear app won't install on the watch.
I follow this document.
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html#PackageManually

The app was created with Eclipce.

In debug mode I can install the wear app and everything works fine.

I use the same package name.
Exported the app with the same key.
And I use real hardware to test a HTC One M7 and the samsung Gear Live.
I install the apk with the "adb install c8.apk".

This is how I release the app.

- Export the wear project if a Android Application.
- Use the same key alias if I use for the phone app.
- rename the .apk to wearable_app.apk
- Put the .apk file in the Phone project  res/raw dir.
- Export the phone project if a Android Application.
- Use the same key alias if I use for the wear app.

Edit: Full Manifest
The Phone manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tild.c8"
    android:versionCode="12"
    android:versionName="1.12" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" />


    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable.beta.app"
            android:resource="@xml/wearable_app_desc"/>

        <activity 
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" 
                    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>        

        <service
            android:name=".ComService"
            android:process=":remote" >
        </service>

        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver> 
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The Wear manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tild.c8"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="20"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
             android:allowEmbedded="true"
             android:taskAffinity=""
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> 
        <service
            android:name=".WearService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The Phone wearable_app_desc.xml in the res/xml dir:

```
<wearableApp package="com.tild.c8">
    <versionCode>1</versionCode>
    <versionName>1.0</versionName>
    <rawParhResId>wearable_app</rawParhResId>
</wearableApp>
```

Comment: Make sure both manifests have the same permissions - this is a security feature since users cannot "accept" new permissions for a wear app. If the wear app requires permissions, the phone app must require them

Comment: The wear app have one permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" />. The phone app has it too.

Comment: OK - you might want to add it to your phone manifest code in your question then :)

Comment: Make sure both apps have exactly the same permissions.

Comment: You mean the wear app need all permissions from the phone app?

Comment: Check the Logs on Wear and Mobile. It often shows an explicit error message :)

Answer (score 2):

I have found the problems.

In the wearable_app_desc.xml rawParhResId need to be rawPathResId.

And the permision  give also a problem. After I remove it the installation is successful.